# Creating terminal command using Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have my university asignment, which looks something like this(original text is in Slovak):

> The result of your work will be an executable program called `command` that will perform transformations on files.
> That is, `command` must be executed as follows:

> `command [OPTION]... [FILE]...`

> The `Makefile` file will contain at least the following targets:
>
> - `all` to generate an executable program named `command`

What have I tried

- Wrap actual `./command` using `source(.)` command

```bash
all:
    . .bashrc
```

where `.bashrc` has next:

```
command() {
    gcc -std=c11 command.c -o command
    ./command
}
```

and it works fine, if I call it just after:

```bash
all:
    . .bashrc && command
```

but not in terminal, where I call `make all`

- using `alias`

```
all:
   alias command=" gcc -std=c11 command.c -o command && ./command"
```

But I have pretty the same result as with `source`

I'm not sure that I'm getting any closer at all, because I'm not so familiar with linux terminal and bash yet. So maybe there is right way to do this, of witch I just didn't think yet?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the translation of your assignment. A better translator may help producing more legible text.

Comment: Using alias is intended for *interactive* shells, e.g. with `alias ll="ls -l"`. Using alias in an `all` target is completely pointless as it does nothing. In addition, `command` is a shell builtin and should not be used as an executable name. Use `cmd` instead, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you show looks... confused. I suggest you start out reading the GNU make manual and a shell manual to familiarize yourself with the operation of `make` and the shell.

To get you started, here's how I would write a Makefile for this:

```
all: cmd
        ./cmd
cmd: cmd.c
        gcc -std=c11 $< -o $@
```

Be sure to use hard tabs to indent the commands. The `$<` and `$@` are make special variables that expand to the dependency `cmd.c` and the target `cmd`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm taking a guess at the interpretation of this question, so forgive me if I misunderstood anything.

The makefile needs to generate an executable.   What you're describing in your attempts is a function -- there's a big difference.   A makefile cannot be used to define a function -- every line in the makefile recipe creates a new shell, and if you define a function in that shell, that function will be go away once that shell exits -- which will be immediately.   I'm guessing the assignment is is to create an actual executable file.   What you're likely looking to do is something like this:

```
all: command
.PHONY: all

command:
    echo "echo doing some command" > $@
    echo "echo doing some other other command" >> $@
    echo "parameter 1 is $$1" >> $@
    chmod +x $@
```

When that's done, you should be able to do `cat command`, and see the script that you created, and you should be able to call `./command param1` to run it.

Some notes:

- Despite what the assignment might say, the `all` target itself should not generate an executable named `command` -- that's just bad practice.  Instead, it can be dependent on another target named `command`.   That target would correctly create an artifact with the same name.   If you build `all`, it will still end up building `command` because `command` is a dependency of `all`

  - The line `.PHONY: all` line simply tells make that `all` is a fake target that doesn't produce an artifact named `all`
- The `command` target generates an executable shell script.

  - the shell script is generated by writing to the file (note: `$@` expands to the target name `command`, so all echos go to that
  - the `chmod +x $@` will change the output file to be executable
  - when dealing with parameters, you have to use double `$$` signs.  Note that `echo "echo $$1" > $@` line will output `echo $1` to `command`.    If you tried `echo $1 > $@`, make would first expand `$1` (which would resolve to blank), and end up putting just `echo`  into `command`. --  `$$` expands to `$` so `$$1` expands to `$1`...
- You may also need a line `command:Makefile`.   This way, if you modify the Makefile to add some new lines to `command`, make will consider `command` out of date, and will rebuild it on its next invocation.   Otherwise, make would only rebuild `command` if it didn't exist.